# Unable to access ElasticSearch on AWS EC2 with private/public ip

Tags: amazon-web-services, rhel6, elasticsearch

I have an Elastic Search running on 9200 on rhel 6. I cannot reach to it in aws with private/public ip. On the other hand, i try it with **curl localhost:9200**, it is good. I can also ping google.

I have given the necessary port access from the security group.

sec inbound allowed port:

[image: sec inbound allowed port]

My /etc/resolv.conf is :

> *generated by /sbin/dhclient-script
>
>   search ec2.internal
>
>   nameserver 172.31.0.2*

UPDATE:
I have also installed an apache webserver on 80 port. And it is responding from the public and private IPs. So the main problem is mainly with Elasticsearch or 9200 port.
Any idea?

Comment: Is it in a public or private subnet? If public, did you assign a public IP to the instance? If private do you have VPN connectivity to the VPC?

Comment: There are automatically assigned public and private IP adresses which appears in the AWS console. With my private key, i can ssh to the machine by using its public IP.

Comment: Updated the question.

Comment: Well, i have found the answer from the web which is below.

Comment: Your current IP rules mean access from ANY address, not from the security group.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default http transport and internal elasticsearch transport only listens to localhost. If you want to access Elasticsearch from the host other than localhost then try adding following configurations in config/elasticsearch.yml.

```
transport.host: localhost 
transport.tcp.port: 9300 
http.port: 9200 
network.host: 0.0.0.0
```

Here, network.host as 0.0.0.0 allow access from any host within the network.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33696944/how-do-i-enable-remote-access-request-in-elasticsearch-2-0